# Quando usar UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: banco-de-dados, time

Com toda certeza, todos trabalhamos com datas, timestamp, entre outros formas e diversos formatos.

O **UNIX_TIMESTAMP** (o tempo em segundos desde '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC até o momento) sempre acaba aparecendo levemente quando vamos a procura de manipulações entre esse tipo de dado.

- Quando é eficaz utilizar-se do **UNIX_TIMESTAMP** ?
- Por ser do tipo numérico, seria uma vantagem na gravação/leitura ?
- A vantagem é somente para quem trabalha com vários fuso horários ?

**Ou seja, brevemente quais são os prós e contras ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa informação demonstra o tempo passado desde 1970. Portanto não pode ser usado para marcar um ponto no tempo qualquer, não pode usar para guardar datas e horários em geral. É uma informação interna do uso de computadores. Considera-se que nada que um computador produziu pode ter ocorrido antes de 1970. Pelo menos em Unixes não pode, então não precisa ser capaz de representar um número anterior a isto.

Ele é um número, sendo o 0 dele marcando 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Assim o 1 seria 1970-01-01 00:00:01 e neste momento o *timestamp* tem o número 1522323093, portanto esta é a quantidade de segundos passados desde o início do ano de 1970.

Existem outras formas de *timestamp* que não seguem esta regra, estou falando apenas do utilizado pelo Unix, derivados e qualquer aplicação que o adote.

Há uma vantagem em ser numérico porque ele é manipulado de forma binária e é muito curo e muito rápido de calcular.

Ele nada tem a ver com fuso horário. Qualquer forma de ponto no tempo pode ou não ter uma informação de fuso horário. Geralmente recomenda-se para a maioria das aplicações, mas existem casos diferentes, que o horário seja sempre UTC, ou seja, o tempo universal sem indicação de qual fuso é, portanto no Brasil o *timestamp* deveria ser usado com menos duas ou menos três horas depende se está em horário de verão ou não. Regras estas que podem mudar, por isto mesmo o horário universal é melhor.

Então use ele para *logs* e outras formas de auditoria, controle de transações, identificações de momentos de eventos gerados dentro do computador, mas não use para armazenar horário em geral. Não use para guardar data de nascimento ou outros eventos na história, não use nem mesmo para armazenar uma data de cadastro porque ela é essencialmente uma informação externa e poderia ter sido cadastrado antes de computadores existirem.

[Em 2038 vai acabar a capacidade dele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) na forma original que foi implementada.